# Splitting array based on specific keywords using php

Tags: arrays, preg-match

I am having such array

```
Array (
    [0] => styles.css 
    [1] => gallerystyle.css 
    [2] => index.php 
    [3] => javascript:; 
    [4] => javascript:; 
    [5] => about.php 
    [6] => gallery.php?id=33 
    [7] => gallery.php?id=30 
    [8] => gallery.php?id=21 
)
```

I want split those arrays in which this pattern is found ".php?"

For instance:

i found this pattern in gallery.php?id=33 so it should display only these kind of arrays based on pattern....any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following functions (ArrayFilterRegExp if you need regular expressions or ArrayFilterStrpos if not).

```
function ArrayFilterRegExp($array, $pattern)
{
    $res = array();
    foreach($array as $a)
        if (preg_match($pattern, $a))
            $res[] = $a;
    return $res;
}
$filtered = ArrayFilterRegExp($array, '#\.php#i');


function ArrayFilterStrpos($array, $find)
{
    $res = array();
    foreach($array as $a)
        if (strpos($a, $find) !== false)
            $res[] = $a;
    return $res;
}
$filtered = ArrayFilterStrpos($array, ".php");
```